# Implement an interface in partial class

Tags: vb.net, class, interface, partial-classes

I need all my `TableAdapters` to implement a custom interface. The problem is that some of the members defined by the interface reside in the DataSet's designer file, which I don't want to (and shouldn't) alter, as that code will be regenerated automatically. I can't relocate those members to my code file either for the same reason. What's my way out of it?

Comment: It is a strongly typed DataSet. Each DataTable has its own TableAdapter, which unfortunately inherits from `Component` instead of `DbTableAdapter` or something more concrete, so I'm trying to fill the gap by implementing my own interface in all those adapters.

Comment: You can create a custom class implementing the interface and extending DataSet or Component or whatever and then use it instead of the predefined UI components. This way you will have your custom behaviour and the TableAdapter at once.

Comment: @pasty: Have you worked with strongly-typed DataSets? That would help a lot to understand what I'm talking about. I have multiple DataTables and each of them has its own TableAdapter. All of them already have those common properties and methods (with precisely same signatures). It's just that these TableAdapter classes do not inherit from a good base class, neither do they implement a common interface, so I have to write the same code for each TableAdapter separately. With a custom interface implemented by all of them, I could use polymorphism to handle all these adapters in one go.

Comment: Yes, I have worked with strongly-typed DataSets. I do believe, that a TableAdapter class can be [extended through a partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233697.aspx) or a base class for a TableAdapter and/or DataSet can be created (that will later be used instead of the predefined components).

Comment: Just create partial classes of each adapter and implement the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement an interface, the members you declare do not have to have the same names as the members of the interface and they don't have to be public.  Let's say that you have this designer-generated class:

```
Partial Public Class SomeClass

    Public Sub FirstMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SecondMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("SecondMethod")
    End Sub

End Class
```

and you want it to implement this interface:

```
Public Interface ISomeInterface

    Sub FirstMethod()

    Sub ThirdMethod()

End Interface
```

Notice that the interface has a method named `FirstMethod` but `SomeClass` already has a method named `FirstMethod`.  You can add your own partial class to implement the interface like this:

```
Partial Public Class SomeClass
    Implements ISomeInterface

    Private Sub FirstMethodInternal() Implements ISomeInterface.FirstMethod
        Me.FirstMethod()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ThirdMethod() Implements ISomeInterface.ThirdMethod
        Console.WriteLine("ThirdMethod")
    End Sub

End Class
```

The method that implements `ISomeInterface.FirstMethod` is not named `FirstMethod` so it doesn't clash with the existing method with that name and it is also `Private` so it cannot be accessed from outside using a reference of type `SomeClass`.  Using a reference of type `ISomeInterface` is another matter though.  If you use code like this:

```
Dim sc As ISomeInterface = New SomeClass

sc.FirstMethod()
sc.ThirdMethod()
```

you'll find that the `FirstMethodInternal` method of your `SomeClass` object gets invoked and, in turn, invokes the `FirstMethod` method of the same object.  Try running that code and placing breakpoints on the `FirstMethod` and `FirstMethodInternal` methods to prove it to yourself.

Comment: This is brilliant. Never realized these could be private. Thanks a bunch.